# acionar function após validação de form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um formulário com validação, e preciso inserir após validar esse formulário uma ampulheta de espera (como se estivesse carregando a pagina).

Gostaria de saber como juntar essas duas funções, sendo que depois de validar o form, aciona a outra:

```
//Validacao cadastro-completo.php
$("#form3").validate({
    rules: {
    constituicao: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 10,
      validadata: true
    },
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
  messages: {
    constituicao: {
      required: "Esse campo é obrigatório",
      minlength: "Data Inválida"
    },
    email: {
      required:"Esse campo é obrigatório",
      email: "Email inválido"
    }
  }
});


function loading() {
    $('body').append("<div class='loading'></div>");        
}
$('.open-loading').click(function () {
    loading();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que eu analisei, dentro do validate tem um atributo chamado : **submitHandler** que você pode colocar o método que será executado após a validação do formulário, conforme o trecho de código abaixo:

```
   function loading() {
        $('body').append("<div class='loading'></div>");        
   }

   $("#form3").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
           loading();
        }
   });
```

O mais simples e verificar na documentação do plugin : https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Há um plugin do javascript chamado [jQuery Form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm). Recentemente postei um [exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/221497/como-submeter-um-formul%C3%A1rio-e-ap%C3%B3s-a-submiss%C3%A3o-carregar-uma-div-com-ajax/221552#221552) de como utilizá-lo.

Ele possui o parâmetro `beforeSubmit` que você pode chamar uma *function* e aplicar `$("#form3").validate()` e ampulheta de espera.

```
beforeSubmit:  valida

// pre-submit callback 
function valida(formData, jqForm, options) { 
    // Aplique as validações do form aqui  
    // O return false previne o submit do form
    // Qualquer retorno ao contrário de false permitirá o submit do form 
    return true; 
}
```